# Rewrite Link to taxonomy page in Views

Tags: views, path-aliases

I am using views to show a list of items from a vocabulary, I want a link under each item to the friendly url for the full view. Currently I am using the rewrite results in views like this:

```
<a href="taxonomy/term/[tid]">Find out more about [name]</a></p>
```

How can I get the friendly url that is setup in pathauto i.e. /partners/google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
Find out more about [name]
```

(without the anchor tag) in `Rewrite the output of this field`, and then use the `Output this field as a link` option and set that to

```
taxonomy/term/[tid]
```

Views will rewrite the link according to Url Alias settings.